# Android API cannot get X509Certificate

Tags: java, android, x509certificate

I have been trying to get subject alternative names from an X509Certificate, but it seems `cert.getSubjectAlternativeNames()` does not work in Android, which returns null.
However, when I use `cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.17")` to extract subject alternative names, the names DO exist and I can parse it byte by byte.

Btw, I am sure my PKCS12 certificate is valid, because I can use `getSubjectAlternativeNames()` and get the correct result in Java program.

Does any body know how to use `getSubjectAlternativeNames()` in Android correctly or I miss some configuration in Android?

Thanks
Aoting

Answer (score 1):

Try using `org.bouncycastle.x509.extension.X509ExtensionUtil.getSubjectAlternativeNames(X509Certificate cert)` as a workaround. If the extension is there, and assuming the bug is not in `X509ExtensionUtil` itself, but in `X509Certificate`, it should work.

Comment: it seems that bouncycastle is too heavy for android

Comment: What do you mean? It is included in Android (it's one of the JRE providers).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that certificate does not contain SubjectAltName extension. Also on which version of Android you are trying this ? There is already an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8409&q=subjectAltName&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)  reported to Google around this, which see to have been resolved in Froyo.

Comment: I am using 2.2. I am sure there is a SubAltName, for Java program can get it

Comment: I am using 2.3. And you are right, 4.0 has more support. Nikolay Elenkov too have mentioned it on their blog.